# I want Odoo 9 no hide wizard on button click

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible disable close wizard on button click in odoo 9, only allow close on X in right corner of wizard. I want on button call function and populate field in wizard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using buttons of type `object` there is the possibility to return an action, which should open the wizard again:

```py
@api.multi
def my_button_method(self):
    # my logic
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'my.wizard.model',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_id': self.id,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.multi
def my_button_method(self):
    # my logic
    return {
        'type': "ir.actions.do_nothing",
    }
```

Clean and simple solution. After clicking button, wizard will stay opened (without reloading) and button will be still active (clickable).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: There is an ir.actions.do_nothing?